Proj construction and Nilpotent Homogenous Elements in Graded Ring
Let $A= \oplus_{n \ge 0} A_n$ a Noetherian graded ring and $f \in A_d$ a nonzero homogeneous element of degree $d>0$. The natural ring map $q:A \to A/(f)$ induces a well defined map $q^*: \operatorname{Proj}(A/(f)) \to \operatorname{Proj}(A)$ of Proj's. Assume, that $q^*$ is a homeomorphism, what can we say about $f$.
Especially, "how far" is $f$ from beeing nilpotent? (Recall, in "affine situation", if $A \to A/(f)$ induces a homeomorphism $\operatorname{Spec}(A/(f)) \to \operatorname{Spec}(A)$, then $f$ is nilpotent.
So this rises the question what is going on with $f$ on Proj setting.
Note, that generalizes this question to the setting where the Proj is constructed abstractly and not as embedding in some $\mathbb{P}_R^N$. There was assumed $A=R[x_0, ..., x_r]/I$ with $I$ saturated ideal, implying that $A$ is generated by $A_1$ and $q^*: \operatorname{Proj}(A/(f)) \to \operatorname{Proj}(A)$ homeo. The question was similar if $f \in I$ or at least nilpotent in $A$. Or at least "which properties" as ring element $f$ should have.
